# How to retrieve the the most recent first row when a coluvalue changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to use ROW_NUMBER/ RANK functions in SQL to retrieve the Date of the most recent Status change for an ID, ignoring any previous instances where an ID was given the same Status code.

For example, for the two IDs shown below I only want to retrieve the row where the Status most recently changed to "8".

| ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 13/02/23 | V |
| 12345 | 14/02/23 | V |
| 12345 | 15/02/23 | 8 |
| 12345 | 16/02/23 | 8 |
| 12345 | 17/02/23 | V |
| 12345 | 18/02/23 | V |
| 12345 | 19/02/23 | 8 |
| 12345 | 20/02/23 | 8 |
| 12345 | 21/02/23 | U |
| 12345 | 22/02/23 | U |
| 12345 | 23/02/23 | 8 |
| 12345 | 24/03/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 07/05/23 | U |
| 67655 | 08/05/23 | U |
| 67655 | 09/05/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 10/05/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 11/05/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 12/05/23 | J |
| 67655 | 13/05/23 | J |
| 67655 | 14/05/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 15/05/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 16/05/23 | 8 |

In this instance it should return the following

| ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 23/02/23 | 8 |
| 67655 | 14/05/23 | 8 |

Secondly, I want to count the number of times the ID went into Status "8", the expected output would be as  below...

| ID | Loops |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 3 |
| 67655 | 2 |

I thought about adding two separate ranklines and then nesting the query, but I couldn't get the numbering to work as expected.

Comment: "I am trying to use ROW_NUMBER/ RANK" - please show us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` with some conditional aggregation:

```
with c as (
  select *, 
    case when Lag(status) over(partition by id order by date)
      != status 
    then 1 end changed
  from t
)
select id, Status, Sum(changed) Loops, Max(date) Date
from c
where changed = 1 and status = '8'
group by id, status;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!